# How can I strip all html tags except <br> in C# code?

Tags: c#, html, regex

What I want to do is to remove all html tags except `<br>` tags.

I have made an example:

```
public string Strip(string text)
{
    return Regex.Replace(text, @”<(.|\n)*?>”, string.Empty);
}
```

But this one removes all.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: @speti43 what do you mean?

Comment: so if you have a full html document (with 150 br tags), you want to remove all content just get 150*<br> as output?

Comment: Its a string with just plain text, and I want to keep the <br> tags and remove all other html tags. Its for a multiline textbox users can change color, weight etc.. But I want to remove that when it gets rendered and just leave linebreaks.

Comment: [Stop processing html with regexes!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Stop saying _"Stop processing html with regexes!"_! For such trivial tasks using regex is much better than using a full-blown XML/HTML parser.

Comment: @DioF: I can't agree with you. `<br>`, `<br/>`, `<br class='clear'/>`, `<bR/>`, `<br \r\n/>` are some possible representations of the `br` tag. Taking all possibilities, including ones that are not *w3c's state of the art*, is quite complex.

Comment: @SteveB In my situation this multiline box sets only "<br>" :)

Comment: @Rohander: I don't understand the requirement. First, are you on Winform, WPF or ASP.Net app? Secondly, why don't you simply use a multine textbox, and replace new lines by `<br/>` at render time?

Comment: @SteveB It's more complicated then that It's sharepoint, it has it own standard  RichTextMode which enables a bunch of  html tools to a field. If I turn it off There wont be any linebreaks.

Comment: In this case, why don't you set up the column as a simple multiline textbox?

Comment: Beacuse when a user does a linebreak <br> should get added and using RichText is a workaround for that but it gives a bunch of other html tools. that wont happen with a simple multiline textbox

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this regex

```
return Regex.Replace(text, @”<(?!br[\x20/>])[^<>]+>”, string.Empty);
```

But I think a html parser might work better with these tasks.

Comment: I've tried this out with my text, but it doesn't work."Your html  <br>  <br><br>text with many <br>" It's just producing the same text.

Comment: That's correct if your string is ``"Your html <br> <br><br>text with many <br>"`` as it keeps all the <br> and remove the rest of html tags. , and since your string doesn't have any other html tags so it produces the same text.

Comment: I thougt he wants to remove all content including the texts also. In that case my suggestion is not useful.

Answer (score 0):

Regex for remove HTML tag in a string except 'br' and 'p' tab. 
Try below Regex

```
Regex.Replace(strText,@"<(?!br[\x20/>])[^<>]+>", String.Empty);
```

Answer (score -1):

To remove any html tag except 'br' and 'p' tab. Use this

```
Regex.Replace(strText,@"<(?!br[\x20/>])[^<>]+>", String.Empty);
```